# R duplicate a matrix several times and then bind by rows together

Tags: r, data-binding, matrix, rbind

I have the following matrix

```
FI1  FI2 YI1 YI2 BAL1 BAL2 GRO1 GRO2  EQ1  EQ2
1 0.22 0.15 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
2 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
3 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
4 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
5 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
6 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Now I would like to have this matrix duplicated 10 times and put in a matrix such that it looks like this (I just show it 2 times here)

```
FI1  FI2 YI1 YI2 BAL1 BAL2 GRO1 GRO2  EQ1  EQ2
1 0.22 0.15 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
2 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
3 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
4 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
5 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
6 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
1 0.22 0.15 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
2 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
3 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
4 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
5 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
6 0.22 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Can somebody propose me a simple way to accomplish this?
Thanks
Andreas

Comment: You'll learn a lot by studying the different answers provided, as each illustrates different tricks and trade-offs.

Answer (score 34):

Here's another way:

```
do.call(rbind, replicate(10, m, simplify=FALSE)) # where m is your matrix
```

Comment: Is this based in a loop or is it vectorized?

Comment: everything's loops if you go down deep enough ;). Typically you use the term "vectorized" to describe a function that operates one-by-one over an atomic vector.

Comment: But `replicate` is just a wrapper for an `sapply` call, which I would call "higher-order" vectorization.

Comment: I've never been comfortable with `do.call` but I like this answer as I can duplicate by row (`rbind`) or column (`cbind`) without changing any additional code or rewriting user defined functions to do it.

Answer (score 16):

The mathematical way to do this is to take the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the matrix with a vector of ones.

```
mX = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
mX %x% rep(1, numTimesToRepeat)
```

Comment: This is a clever solution and will repeat the rows, but in an interdigitated way (i.e., you'll get row 1 repeated `numTimesToRepeat`, and after that row 2 repeated `numTimesToRepeat`). If instead you use `rep(1,numTimesToRepeat) %x% mX`, you'll get the behavior @user2157086 was seeking: you'll go through all of the rows before repeating.

Answer (score 13):

If your matrix is called `m` then you can just use `rep()` as a matrix is really just an atomic vector and then wrap it up with `matrix()` using the columns of your original matrix to get the dimensions right. You have to `transpose` first using `t()` to get the stacking right (thanks to **@MatthewPlourde** for pointing that out). This operation is entirely vectorised so should be very fast and efficient.

```
matrix( rep( t( m ) , 10 ) , ncol = ncol(m) , byrow = TRUE )
```

#### Example

```
m <- matrix( 1:9 , 3 )
matrix( rep( t( m ) , 2 ) , ncol =  ncol(m) , byrow = TRUE )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
#[4,]    1    4    7
#[5,]    2    5    8
#[6,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: OP wants `m` stacked. This transposes and stacks. You could do `matrix(rep(t(m), 2) , ncol=ncol(m) , byrow=TRUE)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever used matlab, the repmat function is very useful, as all you have to do is specify the matrix and how many times you want it replicated row and column wise. Here is an R equivalent:

```
repmat = function(X,m,n){
mx = dim(X)[1]
nx = dim(X)[2]
matrix(t(matrix(X,mx,nx*n)),mx*m,nx*n,byrow=T)} 

m <- matrix(c(1:4), ncol = 2)
repmat(m,2,3)
>
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    1    3    1    3
[2,]    2    4    2    4    2    4
[3,]    1    3    1    3    1    3
[4,]    2    4    2    4    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but simple enough if you just want to keep working:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 10)
str(m)
m2 <- rbind(m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m)
str(m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reprow <- function(x, m) {
    x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), times=m),,drop=FALSE]
}

a <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
b <- reprow(a, 3)
```

If you need the interdigitated way, use `x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), each=m),]` instead.